# Notation for powers of a limit?

Tags: limits, notation

I was trying to find the conventional notation for taking a limit to a power. e.g. for the square of the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$, is
$${\lim_{x\to a}}^2f(x)$$
acceptable? Or would it be better to use the clearer
$$\left[\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right]^2$$?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean the value of the limit squared, the the latter would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have in mind the notion that $\sin^2 x=(\sin x)^2$. That's an old and rather inconsistent convention that has managed to persist (maybe because it's convenient), but I wouldn't try to apply it to anything but the six principal trig functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CW Answer (from comments) to push it out of unanswered queue:

If you mean the value of the limit squared, the the latter would be appropriate.